# Positive Elements and Inequalities in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The following corollary comes from Fillmore's book A User's Guide to Operator Algebras

> **Corollary 2.3.5** $0 \le a \le b \implies ||a|| \le ||b||$

Here is the proof:

> We have $b \le ||b||$ by 2.3.1, and so $a \le ||b||$ by the theorem. Hence $r(a) \le ||b||$ and therefore $||a|| \le ||b||$ by 2.1.3

Why is it the case that $r(a) \le ||b||$? I was unable to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\leq \|b\|-a$, we have $\sigma(\|b\|-a)\subset[0,\infty)$ (here $\sigma(x)$ denotes the spectrum of $x$) and thus $\sigma(a)\subset(-\infty,\|b\|]$.  But $a$ is positive, so $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$, and therefore $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\|b\|]$, i.e., $r(a)\leq\|b\|$.

Comment: I don't see why $\sigma (a) \subseteq (-\infty, ||b||]$ is true; I am unable to verify this.

Comment: Since $\sigma(\|b\|-a)\subset[0,\infty)$, we have $\sigma(-a)\subset[-\|b\|,\infty)$ (shifting by a scalar shifts the spectrum), and thus $\sigma(a)\subset(-\infty,\|b\|]$ (scalar multiplication rescales the spectrum).